# Best way to sort in descending order

Tags: c++, sorting, int

Is it more time-efficient to sort like this:

```
    sort(ar,ar+n,greater<int>());
```

or

```
    bool MyF(int a,int b){ return a>b; }
    sort(ar,ar+n,MyF);
```

Comment: `std::greater` is a pre-made, superior version of that function.

Comment: What is `ar`?​​ Is it "better" according to which metrics?

Comment: When I write ar I mean my array, and better according to time

Comment: Simply measure the [time](http://www.songho.ca/misc/timer/timer.html) difference between the two.

Comment: Yes I can do this, thank you nils

Comment: Don't follow that tutorial. It misses out some crucial steps of benchmarking. You will get wrong results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on what `ar` is. If it's a sequence container, the reverse iterators are your friends:

```
std::sort(ar.rbegin(), ar.rend());
```

Otherwise, yeah, `std::greater<int>` seems appropriate for the task...

As for which of your two examples is "better", well, they are functionally equivalent and the former uses a standard library feature that is tested and does the job for you. I see no contest, frankly.